# Error using transformation with Glide 4.7

Tags: android, android-glide

When I switched to the new version of `Glide` (4.7.1) I had to make some changes in the code. Where I used to have:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .bitmapTransform(ContrastFilterTransformation(activity, BaseActivity.CONTRAST_IMAGES))
        .centerCrop()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
        .into(imageView)
```

now I have:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .transform(
                                ContrastFilterTransformation(
                                        context,
                                        BaseActivity.CONTRAST_IMAGES
                                )
                        )
        )
        .into(imageView)
```

The problem is that now I get the error reported below and the image is not loaded.
The loaded image is a jpg file downloaded from the internet.
If I get rid of the transformation the image is loaded correctly.
If I get rid of everything but the transformation in the `RequestOptions`, I still get the error.
The same error happens if I set `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.None)` 
This used to work with the `Glide` version 2 and the old code.

> I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
>       java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.bumptech.glide.load.Key.updateDiskCacheKey(java.security.MessageDigest)"
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawableTransformation.updateDiskCacheKey(GifDrawableTransformation.java:67)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheKey.updateDiskCacheKey(ResourceCacheKey.java:83)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.SafeKeyGenerator.calculateHexStringDigest(SafeKeyGenerator.java:52)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.SafeKeyGenerator.getSafeKey(SafeKeyGenerator.java:41)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.DiskLruCacheWrapper.get(DiskLruCacheWrapper.java:88)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheGenerator.startNext(ResourceCacheGenerator.java:86)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)